# Problema con campos null en query sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo una pequeña situación con un query que esta realizando una consulta a 3 tablas las cuales me traen un registro de la cantidad de contenedores que tiene cada ubicación con su producto.

Este es mi query

```sql
SELECT A.Location AS 'BAHIA', C.Part_No AS 'MODELO', 
    A.Cube_Max_Weight AS 'CAPACIDAD MAXIMA DE LA BAHIA', 

    ISNULL((
      SELECT COUNT(B.Serial_No) 
      FROM Part_v_Container B 
      WHERE B.Active = 1 
        AND A.Location = B.Location 
        and B.Part_Key = C.Part_Key
    ),0)  AS 'CONTENEDORES EN LA BAHIA'
           
FROM Common_v_Location_e A

    LEFT JOIN Part_v_Container B ON A.Location = B.Location
    LEFT JOIN Part_v_Part C ON B.Part_Key = C.Part_Key

WHERE A.Location_Type = 'Storage' 
    AND A.Location_Group_Key = '3554' 
    AND (A.Note LIKE '%Producto Terminado%' AND A.Location LIKE 'B1%') 


GROUP BY A.Location, C.Part_No, A.Cube_Max_Weight,C.Part_Key
ORDER BY A.Location
```

El problema es que me trae productos que no están en la locación

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En dado caso si la ubicación estuviera vacía solo que me mostrara ubicación vacía y la cantidad en 0

Comment: Es como dice Luis Cazares en su respuesta: Las cantidades son ceros, porque `Active <> 1`. Además parece inadecuado consultar la tabla Part_v_Container  dos veces. El  GROUP BY` sugere que los joins de dan combinaciones de locación y parte varias veces. ¿Cuál tabla está causando esto? ¿Cuales son las llaves de tus tablas? ¿Es Location llave de Common_v_Location_e? ¿Es Part_Key llave de Part_v_Part? Y Part_v_Container puede tener mas de una fila por un Location y Part_Key, ¿verdad? Supongo que la llave de esta tabla es Location + Part_Key + Serial_No. ¿Es así?

Comment: Por favor dinos lo que queres hacer exactamente: ¿Quieres mostrar partes que solamente existen como inactivas en una locación o no? ¿Quieres contar todas las partes o solamente las activas?

Comment: Por cierto, `AS 'BAHIA'` no es SQL válido, porque nombres y aliases requieren comillas dobles (`"`) en SQL, y corchetes en SQL Server (`[]`). Bueno, parece que SQL Server no es nada de riguroso al respecto a esa regla. `COUNT(B.Serial_No)` es lo mismo que `COUNT(*)`, si Serial_No no puede ser NULL. (¿Es posible que es NULL esta columna en tu tabla? Deberías usar `COUNT(expresión)` solamente, si la expresión puede ser NULL, para claridad de tu consulta.) Y `COUNT(algo)` nunca produce NULL, entonces `ISNULL` no es necesario.

Answer (score 1):

No creo que te esté trayendo productos que no estén en la ubicación. Más bien te trae productos que están en la ubicación en contenedores inactivos.

Para hacer más fácil la depuración del código, vamos a darle formato:

```
SELECT  L.Location AS 'BAHIA', 
        P.Part_No AS 'MODELO', 
        L.Cube_Max_Weight AS 'CAPACIDAD MAXIMA DE LA BAHIA', 
        ISNULL((SELECT COUNT(CC.Serial_No) 
                FROM Part_v_Container CC 
                WHERE CC.Active   = 1  
                AND   L.Location  = CC.Location 
                and   CC.Part_Key = P.Part_Key),0)  AS 'CONTENEDORES EN LA BAHIA'
FROM      Common_v_Location_e   AS L
LEFT JOIN Part_v_Container      AS C ON L.Location = C.Location
LEFT JOIN Part_v_Part           AS P ON C.Part_Key = P.Part_Key
WHERE L.Location_Type       = 'Storage' 
AND   L.Location_Group_Key  = '3554'  
AND   L.Note                LIKE '%Producto Terminado%' 
AND   L.Location            LIKE 'B1%'
GROUP BY L.Location,
         P.Part_No, 
         L.Cube_Max_Weight,
         P.Part_Key
ORDER BY L.Location;
```

Si te fijas, en la subconsulta estás agregando una condición adicional.

Creo que la consulta se puede simplificar más quitando esa subconsulta.

```
SELECT  L.Location AS 'BAHIA', 
        P.Part_No AS 'MODELO', 
        L.Cube_Max_Weight AS 'CAPACIDAD MAXIMA DE LA BAHIA', 
        COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN CC.Active = 1 THEN C.Serial_No END) AS 'CONTENEDORES EN LA BAHIA'
FROM      Common_v_Location_e   AS L
LEFT JOIN Part_v_Container      AS C ON L.Location = C.Location
LEFT JOIN Part_v_Part           AS P ON C.Part_Key = P.Part_Key
WHERE L.Location_Type       = 'Storage' 
AND   L.Location_Group_Key  = '3554'  
AND   L.Note                LIKE '%Producto Terminado%' 
AND   L.Location            LIKE 'B1%'
GROUP BY L.Location,
         P.Part_No, 
         L.Cube_Max_Weight,
         P.Part_Key
ORDER BY L.Location;
```

Aunque es probable que quieras mantener esa condición para toda la consulta

```
SELECT  L.Location AS 'BAHIA', 
        P.Part_No AS 'MODELO', 
        L.Cube_Max_Weight AS 'CAPACIDAD MAXIMA DE LA BAHIA', 
        COUNT(DISTINCT C.Serial_No) AS 'CONTENEDORES EN LA BAHIA'
FROM      Common_v_Location_e   AS L
LEFT JOIN Part_v_Container      AS C ON L.Location = C.Location
LEFT JOIN Part_v_Part           AS P ON C.Part_Key = P.Part_Key
WHERE L.Location_Type       = 'Storage' 
AND   L.Location_Group_Key  = '3554'  
AND   L.Note                LIKE '%Producto Terminado%' 
AND   L.Location            LIKE 'B1%'
AND   C.Active              = 1
GROUP BY L.Location,
         P.Part_No, 
         L.Cube_Max_Weight,
         P.Part_Key
ORDER BY L.Location;
```